# ng-click not working inside item in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I am not able to get the ng-click event to trigger when inside an item in a ionic modal that pops up. When I click on an item I see it turn gray so it seems like it is registering the click but I have a console.log statement as the first line in my joinGroup function and nothing is output to the console.

I also tried using the ion-list and ion-item elements but those didn't work either.

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Join Court</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Done</button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="group in groups"  ng-click="joinGroup(group)">
        <h2>{{group.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{group.address}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>

var joinGroup = function (group) {

  console.log("Call joinGroup");
```

Comment: define joinGroup on $scope. $scope.joinGroup = function (group) {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Join Court</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Done</button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="group in groups" >
        <ion-item  ng-click="joinGroup(group)">
           <h2>{{group.name}}</h2>
           <p>{{group.address}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

In your controller try to do with **$scope** when writing function like this.

```
$scope.groups = [];
$scope.joinGroup = function(){

   //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohan! I had declared $scope.groups but forgot to define the function with $scope. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did not connect your view with your controller correctly

either you have

```
.controller('myCtl', myCtl);

function myCtl($scope) {

   $scope.groups = [];
   $scope.joinGroup = function(args) {};

}
```

and your view

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl">
   <ion-content class="padding">
       <ion-list ng-repeat="group in groups" >
           <ion-item ng-click="joinGroup(group)">
               <h2>{{group.name}}</h2>
               <p>{{group.address}}</p>
           </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
</div>
```

or you can use this approach, which I prefer

```
.controller('myCtl', myCtl);

function myCtl() {

   var vm = this;

   vm.groups = [];
   vm.joinGroup = function(args) {};

}
```

view

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl as vm">
   <ion-content class="padding">
       <ion-list ng-repeat="group in vm.groups" >
           <ion-item ng-click="vm.joinGroup(group)">
               <h2>{{group.name}}</h2>
               <p>{{group.address}}</p>
           </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks matt93! I had declared $scope.groups but forgot to define the function with $scope. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define angular module and angular controller
and put the

```
app.controller('name',function($scope){
   $scope.joinGroup = function(group){
 console.log("Call joinGroup");
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks Abdou! I had declared $scope.groups but forgot to define the function with $scope. That resolved the issue.